# After installing Elementary os. computer won't boot

Tags: system-installation

On booting up,I get a message to select proper boot device and reboot. I tried changing bios settings but nothing works.

Comment: assuming you installed Elementary correctly ... it sounds like grub was not installed ... or you placed it in a "non-boot" partition ... since this is a new install and that does not take ling to do ... the simplest thing may be to install again and take carefull note of what you are doing for disk partitioning AND where the grub loader is going ... this should probably be on a device and not a partition ... no number on the file ... something like /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no operating system / boot loader on your system. You will have to reinstall or repair elementary OS as there is something that went wrong.